# Raspberry Pi Zero - Is it USB OTG, or just a female micro USB connector?

Tags: usb, pi-zero

I can't seem to tell if the Raspberry Pi Zero's female micro USB port is and/or requires USB OTG.  I see a lot of people talking about USB OTG on the Zero, but the specs I've seen don't mention USB OTG, just USB.

Therefore, do you need a USB OTG cable, or can a simple [physical adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0027YYMU6) be used in conjunction with the Pi Zero?

Edit

The [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) is the best way to read up on USB OTG and what makes it different from USB.

Comment: For what it's worth I use one of these http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/271971005767

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The port is USB OTG. All discussions on [RPi.org's blog](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-zero/) and the fact that most vendors provide according adapter kits point that way.

Answer (score 2):

A USB OTG connector is just a micro USB male to USB type A female but some of the pins are grounded and there are extra pins. You can still use any type of micro USB cord that supports data and power, or you can use an OTG cable. So yes, a physical adapter would work fine.

Comment: No, that's not all. USB OTG has a fifth pin, and certain pins shorted.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go#OTG_micro_plugs

Comment: @allanonmage huh, I've seen people just use a regular micro usb cable and it worked fine. I'll edit my answer.